# Time.h Providing Incorrect Answer in C

Tags: c, arrays, date, pointers, time

I have an array of dates, which are currently integers in the format {2010, 5, 13, 2010, 5, 15} and so on. I am trying to use the time.h library to find the difference in days between each date. Here is some code that portrays what is going wrong:

```
int main()
{
    int dates[] = {2010, 4, 14, 2010, 4, 15, 2010, 4, 16};
    int* pDates = dates;
    printf("%d\n", subtractDates(1, pDates));
    return 0;
}

int subtractDates(int i, int* pDates)
{
  struct tm start_date;
  struct tm end_date;
  time_t start_time, end_time;

  start_date.tm_hour = 0;  
  start_date.tm_min = 0;  
  start_date.tm_sec = 0;
  start_date.tm_mon = *(pDates+1)-1; 
  start_date.tm_mday = *(pDates+2); 
  start_date.tm_year = *(pDates)-1900;

  end_date.tm_hour = 0;  
  end_date.tm_min = 0;  
  end_date.tm_sec = 0;
  end_date.tm_mon = *(pDates+1+i*3)-1; 
  end_date.tm_mday = *(pDates+2+i*3); 
  end_date.tm_year = *(pDates+i*3)-1900;
  start_time = mktime(&start_date);
  end_time = mktime(&end_date);

  return difftime(end_time, start_time) / 86400;
}
```

This code print outs that the difference between the dates provided is 1 day, which is correct. However, if I remove the third date in the array, like below, the printed value becomes 0, which I do not believe is correct.

```
int main()
{
    int dates[] = {2010, 4, 14, 2010, 4, 15};
    int* pDates = dates;
    printf("%d\n", subtractDates(1, pDates));
    return 0;
}

int subtractDates(int i, int* pDates)
{
  struct tm start_date;
  struct tm end_date;
  time_t start_time, end_time;

  start_date.tm_hour = 0;  
  start_date.tm_min = 0;  
  start_date.tm_sec = 0;
  start_date.tm_mon = *(pDates+1)-1; 
  start_date.tm_mday = *(pDates+2); 
  start_date.tm_year = *(pDates)-1900;

  end_date.tm_hour = 0;  
  end_date.tm_min = 0;  
  end_date.tm_sec = 0;
  end_date.tm_mon = *(pDates+1+i*3)-1; 
  end_date.tm_mday = *(pDates+2+i*3); 
  end_date.tm_year = *(pDates+i*3)-1900;
  start_time = mktime(&start_date);
  end_time = mktime(&end_date);

  return difftime(end_time, start_time) / 86400;
}
```

I just don't understand why it is returning 0 considering that all I have done is remove three values in the array, and those three values were not even used in the first program. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't be printing `double`s with `%d`.

Comment: So, good thing you're only using it to print ints.

Comment: Works for me: https://ideone.com/lytPf4

Comment: You should be checking the return from `mktime()` and filling in the `tm_isdst` member, which is currently getting passed to `mktime()` uninitialized and containing garbage. You have no moral right to expect things to be working if you don't take a moment to check whether they actually are.

Comment: You are using `difftime`, which returns a double, not an int. Please address that issue by changing the return statement to `return difftime(end_time, start_time) / 86400.0;`, the return type of your function to `double` and your `printf` format to `"%f"`

Comment: Thanks guys, the data types were the issue.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths, Woops, didn't even notice the return type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that I was having is that I was assigning and returning doubles as integers. By just making amendments regarding this I was able to get my code to work. Thanks to everyone who helped.